# Forward logs via rsyslog to Datadog without agents?

Tags: docker, syslog

I'm trying to forward my container logs ( apache2 access.log on Febian container) to datadog but it didn't work. I followed this [tutorial][1].

This is rsyslog.conf file:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################
$MaxMessageSize 64k
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
#module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
#$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info           -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*
```

and this is my /etc/rsyslog.d/datadog.conf

```
$template DatadogFormat,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% - - - %msg%\n"

ruleset(name="infiles") {
    action(type="omfwd" target="intake.logs.datadoghq.com" protocol="tcp" port="514" template="DatadogFormat")
}

input(type="imfile" ruleset="infiles" Tag="mkmd" File="/var/log/apache2/access.log")
```

anyone has an idea about this ?
[1]: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/rsyslog/?tab=datadogeusite#setup

Answer (score 0):

The port is wrong, you have 514 and the docs say 10514 (or 10516 for TLS).

Also you might need `StateFile="<UNIQUE_FILE_ID>"` in your input

`input(type="imfile" ruleset="infiles" Tag="mkmd" File="/var/log/apache2/access.log" StateFile="<UNIQUE_FILE_ID>")`